# Join author names with first ones separated by comma and last one by "and"

Tags: python, join

I'm completely new to Python and have a list of names separated by `\and`, which I need to join separating the first ones with comma and the last one by 'and'. However if there are more than 4 names the return value should be the first name along with the phrase 'et al.'. So if I have

```
 authors = 'John Bar \and Tom Foo \and Sam Foobar \and Ron Barfoo'
```

I should get 'John Bar et al.'. Whereas with

```
authors = 'John Bar \and Tom Foo \and Sam Foobar'
```

I should get 'John Bar, Tom Foo and Sam Foobar'.

It should also work with just one author name, returning that single name (and surname) by itself.

I tried doing something like

```
  names = authors.split('\and')
  result = ', '.join(names[:-1]) + ' and '.join(names[-1])
```

But that obviously doesn't work. So my question is how can I use `join` and `split` to get the first authors separated by comma and the last by 'and' taking into account that if there are more than four authors only the first author name should be returned along with 'et al.'.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: take a look at the str.split() method: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: Are you sure about `'\and'`? It should be `r'\and'` or `'\\and'`.

Comment: You should tell more about how you tried to take on the problem (code, basic algorithm), so the help can be focused rather than doing your work for you.

Comment: authors.split(' \and ') is a good place to start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with splitting out the names:

```
names = [name.strip() for name in authors.split(r'\and')]  # assuming a raw \ here, not the escape code \a.
```

Then rejoin based on the length:

```
if len(names) >= 4:
    authors = '{} et al.'.format(names[0])
elif len(names) > 1:
    authors = '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(names[:-1]), names[-1])
else:
    authors = names[0]
```

This works for entries with just *one* author too; we just reassign the name to `authors`.

Combined into a function:

```
def reformat_authors(authors):
    names = [name.strip() for name in authors.split(r'\and')]
    if len(names) >= 4:
        return '{} et al.'.format(names[0])
    if len(names) > 1:
        return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(names[:-1]), names[-1])
    return names[0]
```

with a demo:

```
>>> reformat_authors(r'John Bar \and Tom Foo \and Sam Foobar \and Ron Barfoo')
'John Bar et al.'
>>> reformat_authors(r'John Bar \and Tom Foo \and Sam Foobar')
'John Bar, Tom Foo and Sam Foobar'
>>> reformat_authors(r'John Bar \and Tom Foo')
'John Bar and Tom Foo'
>>> reformat_authors(r'John Bar')
'John Bar'
```

Comment: This will return ` and John Bar` for an entry with just one author. *edit* Oh, you just fixed it; nevermind :-)

Comment: Nice, although using `join()` for lists of a fixed size of two is a bt overkill, don't you think?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It is a holdover from a `filter(bool, ..)` approach that I thought better of.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the help. However I don't understand why I got as many down-votes as answers. Even after I edited my question I got new down-votes.

Comment: My guess is that people voted that way because you didn't show any research effort yourself. You basically asked people to write code for you. I can only guess at the motivations though.

Answer (score 2):

Let's split this problems into parts:

First, get a list of the individual authors:

```
>>> authors = 'John Bar \\and Tom Foo \\and Sam Foobar \\and Ron Barfoo'
>>> authorlist = [item.strip() for item in authors.split("\\and")]
>>> authorlist
['John Bar', 'Tom Foo', 'Sam Foobar', 'Ron Barfoo']
```

Now check for the number of entries in the list and act accordingly:

```
>>> if len(authorlist) > 3:
...     print("{0} et al.".format(authorlist[0]))
... elif len(authorlist) == 1:
...     print(authorlist[0])
... else:
...     print("{0} and {1}".format(", ".join(authorlist[:-1]), authorlist[-1]))
...
John Bar et al.
```

Comment: @PiotrHajduga: Yikes! Thank you for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def natural_join(val, cnj="and"):
    if isinstance(val, list):
        return " ".join((", ".join(val[0:-1]), "%s %s" % (cnj, val[-1]))) if len(val) > 1 else val[0]
    else:
        return val

natural_join(['pierre'])
# 'pierre'

natural_join(['pierre', 'paul'])
# 'pierre and paul'

natural_join(['pierre', 'paul', 'jacques'])
# 'pierre, paul and jacques'

natural_join(['pierre', 'paul', 'jacques'], cnj="et")
# 'pierre, paul et jacques'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should split your tring, to get the names using `split`.

```
parts = author.split(' \and ')
```

Then You apply your conditions:

1. If there are 4 or more names, return the first name + ' el at'

   ```
   if len(parts) >= 4:
       return parts[0]+' et al'
   ```
2. If there are more than 1 names, join them with a ', ' and the last one with a ' and '

   ```
   elif len(parts) > 1:
       return ' and '.join([', '.join(parts[:-1]), parts[-1]])
   ```
3. If there is only one name, return that name.

   ```
   return parts[0]
   ```

The final function:

```
def my_func(author):
    parts = author.split(' \and ')
    if len(parts) >= 4:
        return parts[0]+' et al'
    elif len(parts) > 1:
        return ' and '.join([', '.join(parts[:-1]), parts[-1]])
    return parts[0]
```

Comment: missing the and in the result

Comment: Initially I had the same objection as cmd, but now your solution returns `' and John Bar'` in the case where there's only one author.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should check out the `string.split` method. You've got a few cases here: either there's one name, there are 2-3 names, or there are 4+ names. Each of these needs separate handling, so just figure out what needs to be done in each case:

```
# First split up the names by your specified delimiter (and strip off whitespace)
names = [name.strip() for name in authors.split(r'\and')]

# Now deal with your three cases for formatting.
if len(names) == 1:
    print names[0]
elif len(names) < 4:
    print ', '.join(names[:-1])+' and '+names[-1]
else:
    print names[0]+' et al.'
```